# $\exp_{x}$ is only $C^{1}$ at $y=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, metric-spaces

According to the following image of book "Riemann-Finsler geometry" by chern & shen
[image: valid XHTML]
<sub>(source: [picofile.com](http://s6.picofile.com/file/8244644368/4.jpg))</sub>

I would like to know which theorem of ODE theory is applied?

Thanks.